# How to print same pack multiple times on GUI in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("200x200")

options = tk.Label(text = "Text")

for i in range (3):
      options.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

I want this to print "Text" in the gui, 3 times, on 3 different lines. Any help pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("200x200")


for i in range (3):
      options = tk.Label(window, text="test label")
      options.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

This will work.